# Write a file byte by byte in C using fwrite()

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to read a file byte by byte and write it to another file. I have this code:

```
if((file_to_write = fopen(file_to_read, "ab+")) != NULL){

  for(i=0; i<int_file_size; i++){
    curr_char = fgetc(arch_file);

    fwrite(curr_char, 1, sizeof(curr_char), file_to_write);
  }
}
```

where `int_file_size` is the amount of bytes I want to read, `arch_file` is the file I'm reading from, and `curr_char` is a char pointer.

However this doesn't work. I get Segmentation fault (core dumped) error on the first iteration in the loop. I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with my fwrite() statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not the source of your problem, but calling `fwrite(&c, 1, 1, file)` is likely to be a hundred times slower than `putc(c, f)` and does the exact same thing.

Comment: I never saw that function before, but yeah it does look simpler. I don't understand how it could be faster though, isn't it just reading each character (byte by byte) from the input file and writing it to the output file?

Comment: The difference is that `putc` knows from the beginning that it's just writing one byte. `fwrite` expects to be writing something potentially much larger and must calculate the total length (multiplication), and work out the optimal strategy for whether to buffer it or immediately write it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should pass the *address* of `curr_char`, not the `curr_char` itself:

```
fwrite(&curr_char, 1, sizeof(curr_char), file_to_write);
//     ^------ Here
```

Answer (score 4):

> `curr_char` is a char pointer.

In that case,

```
curr_char = fgetc(arch_file);
```

is wrong. You're implicitly converting the `int` returned by `fgetc` to a `char*`, and then in `fwrite`, that value is interpreted as an address, from which the `sizeof(char*)` bytes are tried to be read and written to the file.

If `curr_char` points to memory allocated for a `char`,

```
*curr_char = fgetc(arch_file);
fwrite(curr_char, 1, sizeof *curr_char, file_to_write);
```

would be closer to correctness. But `fgetc` returns an `int` and not a `char` for a reason, it may fail, in which case it returns `EOF`. So you should have

```
int chr = fgetc(arch_file);
if (chr == EOF) {
    break;  // exit perhaps?
}
char c = chr;  // valid character, convert to `char` for writing
fwrite(&c, 1, sizeof c, file_to_write);
```

to react to file reading errors.

Comment: Good point. I've been getting so many compile warnings about this. Thanks.