# How to correctly set size and count parameters for fwrite() to write a chunk of bytes?

Tags: c++, c, fwrite

Looking at the spec for [`fwrite(const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/), I'm unsure what exactly goes into the `size` parameter and the `count` parameter when writing binary data, i.e. a chunk of bytes.

Do I have to tell fwrite to *write `bufLen` blocks of size 1*, or should I tell it to *write 1 block of size `bufLen`*? Is any of these better? How does it affect the returned value? How does it affect the behaviour in the case of an error?
If I specify to write one block of size `bufLen`, does it always write either the complete data or nothing?

In code, it looks like this:

```
char* buf = ...;
int bufLen = ...;
FILE* file = ...;

/* alternative 1: */ int writtenByteCount = fwrite(buf, 1, bufLen, file);
/* alternative 2: */ int writtenByteCount = fwrite(buf, bufLen, 1, file);

printf("fwrite wrote %i of %i bytes/blocks", writtenByteCount, bufLen);

if (writtenByteCount < bufLen) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate, because `fwrite()` usage must be extremely widespread, but I couldn't find this question on SO.

Comment: `size: Size in bytes of each element to be written.` and `count: Number of elements, each one with a size of size bytes.`

Comment: @Gasim, I already read that. It doesn't help me, because you can understand this in both ways. Is binary data one element of n bytes or is it n elements of length 1?

Comment: @DanielS. Found an earlier thread.

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002367/write-a-file-byte-by-byte-in-c-using-fwrite and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/

Comment: the count should be 1 logically because its the count, while size is size of each element. Just think of it this way. If you are writing some random class multiple times into a file, you should write the size as `sizeof(structNameHere)` and count as the number of times you want it. But result wise, i think they should both be the same because they are likely to multiply.

Comment: if `fwrite` goes through a loop, trying to create each element separately, it will be unnecessarily long loop if you use count for the bytes. For example, if you have 1 object of size 4Mbs, I would want the loop to go once and then copy; instead of looping 4096 times and copy one byte on each iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fwrite()` function shall write, from the array pointed to by `ptr`, up to `nitems` elements whose size is specified by `size`, to `stream`.

For each object( `nitems` times for a `fwrite()` call), `size` calls shall be made to the `fputc()`, taking the values (in order) from an array of unsigned char exactly overlaying the object.

> As long as the underlying writes are buffered (which is commonly the case for most filesystems), the difference in performance of both the cases will be quite negligible.

The file-position indicator for the stream (if defined) shall be advanced by the number of bytes successfully written. If an error occurs, the resulting value of the file-position indicator for the stream is unspecified.

---

How the two variants differ is when partial writes are performed and `fwrite()` returns. Then having a smaller `size` and larger `nitems` provides a higher granularity in the return value.

For example if ONLY 5 bytes were written (in an attempt to write 10 bytes),

```
// case 1
fwrite(bufptr, 1, 10, fptr);
// returns 5. As 5 out of 10 items written successfully

// case 2
fwrite(bufptr, 10, 1, fptr);
// returns 0. As 0 out of 1 item written
```